# Django POST using AJAX not working

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.x, cors, django-cors-headers

I have a django backend where I have added corsheader and the middlewares.

I have an html page from which I am sending AJAX XMLHttpRequest POST to my localhost hosting django application but the post never goes through. It fires a GET transaction and the transaction never reaches the server.

The code for the front end HTML page is as below:-

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="sub1" 
onClick=loadDoc() >Login </button>
<script>
                    function loadDoc() {
                        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
                                location.replace(Trial.html);
                            }
                        };
                        xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/", true)
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        xhttp.send();
                    }
</script>
```

Can any one point out what is wrong? When I use form data the post works but it doesn't work when I use javascript.

Comment: What is the local endpoint being served with? Django REST Framework? Or a view returning `application/json`? Is the endpoint CSRF exempt? I may have an example depending on the answers in jQuery.

Comment: The endpoint is just a view handling the url being requested from the html page. The banckend is csrf exempt. The view is just returing a success string for now, but ultimately I will return json once it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that happening is CORS.

Modern browsers don't support cross origin requests. So, I had to download and install Django CORS header module. Update the settings file appropriately to allow requests from other origin to come through.

Also, the AJAX/jQuery post request was changed to:

```
 $( "#loginForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
     // Stop form from submitting normally
     event.preventDefault();

     var jqxhr = $.post( "http://XXXX.com/xxxx/xxxx/", $( "#loginForm" ).serialize(), function() {
                            alert( "success" );
                      })
                            .done(function( data ) {
                                if( data == "SUCCESS") {
                                    location.replace("xxxx.html");
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert("WRONG CREDS");
                                }
                        })
                            .fail(function() {
                            alert( "error" );
                        });
                    });
```